# How to change images dynamically

Tags: php, html, mysql

On a HTML file I am using the following code to show images on a popup window:

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "BONOS ALQUILER 2/6" href="eventos/Bonos_alquiler.jpg">one</a>
                <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "CICLO 3/6" href="eventos/Ciclo.jpg">one</a>
                <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "PEQUE TENIS/PADEL 4/6" href="eventos/PEQUES-padel_tenis.jpg">one</a>
                <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "PILATES 5/6" href="eventos/Pilates.jpg">one</a>
                <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery01" title= "ZUMBA 6/6" href="eventos/Zumba.jpg">one</a>
</div>
```

Now, what I need is to change the images dynamically. 
I need to show the images that are included in a server folder. 
On the current server I can't use data bases, but I have access to another server where I could use a data base to store the images title and path.
What could I do to change the previous code to allow me to change the images that are stored on a folder or that are stored in a database?
What is the best solution to my problem?

Comment: You need to use ajax. Write a php file that gets the image url from database and outputs a json response with the url. Send ajax request to the php file. Fetch the json decode it and change the image file urls.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy, I have decided to create a folder in the server to upload the images and then use PHP to read the files that are on that folder. This is my solution, taken from Github:

```
<?php
    # To prevent browser error output
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
    # Path to image folder
    $imagefolder = 'eventos/';
    # Show only these file types in the image folder
    $imagetypes = '{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.png,*.PNG,*.gif,*.GIF}';
    # Add images to array
    $images = glob($imagefolder.$imagetypes, GLOB_BRACE);
    # Sort the images based on its 'last modified' time stamp
    $sortedImages = array();
    $count = count($images);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sortedImages[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($images[$i])).$i] = $images[$i];
    }
    # Set to 'false' if you want the oldest images to appear first
    $newest_images_first = true;
    # Sort images in array
    if($newest_images_first) {
        krsort($sortedImages);
    } else {
        ksort($sortedImages);
    }

    foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {
        # Get the name of the image, stripped from image folder path and file type extension
        $name = 'Polideportivo Los Cedros: '.substr($image,strlen($imagefolder),strpos($image, '.')-strlen($imagefolder));

    echo "  <a class='fancybox' rel='gallery01' title= '".$name."' href='".$image."'></a>";

    }

?>
```

May be there are better solutions, but this works for me.